# Counting date entries from file. - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a file which have several lines with different timestamps, however I want to count the timestamps from the last 15 minutes.

Counting timestamps would be easy enough, but I cannot figure out how to get the timestamps from the last 15 minutes.

Example of timestamps

```
2020-07-20T18:00:00Z
```

I have tried several things, but I couldn't get them to work. Perhaps it's just me...

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15) ....

Comment: in addition to the code you have tried [and how it failed to meet your needs], please post a few lines of your sample data and what you want from that specific sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the formatting in your original file looks like but this code will count the entries within the last 15 minutes.

```bsh
$lastFifteenMinutesCount = 0
$comparisonDate = [datetime]::UtcNow

Get-Content C:\tmp\overflow\63003625\stuff.txt | % {
  if ($_ -match '(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}Z)') {
    $sDate = [datetime]::Parse($Matches[1]).ToUniversalTime().AddMinutes(15)
    if ($sDate -ge $comparisonDate) {
      $lastFifteenMinutesCount++
    }
  }
}

$lastFifteenMinutesCount
```